# change DNS name on raspbian (debian)

Tags: debian, dns, hostname, raspberry-pi

I just installed raspbian on my raspberry pi, and was wondering why I can't use it's hostname from other machines.

on my router, I can see which computers are connected by their name, for example a windows pc, a mac, my iphone, etc... all have names. But for my Pi, I see only the ip adress.

on the pi, I have set hostname correctly, like this:

```
pi@pi ~ $ sysctl kernel.hostname
kernel.hostname = pi
```

hostname also delivers:

```
pi@pi ~ $ hostname
pi
```

but hostname -d won't deliver anything:

```
pi@pi ~ $ hostname -d 
pi@pi ~ $
```

why is this? why can't I run `ping pi` on any other machine and get to the pi?

thanks

Comment: `hostname -d` is unreliable; RTFM. I think you need to provide more information about your router, and `/etc/host*`s, and `/etc/resolv.conf`s of the hosts, for a useful answer. `ping` resolves names according to DNS: if the host pinged from can't resolve it, it asks the next DNS server; on WLAN routers that is usually coupled with a DHCP server. I think the DNS server can't know about the hostname if the target host doesn't tell it implicitly when requesting an IP address via a [DHCP vendor extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP#DHCP_options). This question is probably too localized.

Comment: Thanks @PointedEars for your comment. I have a fritz.box router. As I said, all other machines tell the DHCP server on the router their name... but the pi doesn't. `resolv.conf` shows the following line: `nameserver 192.168.178.1` which is the router's ip. I edited `hosts` with the line `127.0.0.1 pi`... should I put here the real ip? what if it changes? i`m using dhcp on the pi.

Comment: As your router is the primary DNS server for your clients, it is as I said. You need to configure your Raspian to tell the router on DHCP handshake what the client's hostname is. A change in your DHCP client configuration in `/etc/dhcp*` to use the vendor extension is more likely to help than the FQDN in the `hosts` file. With dhclient 4.x, there should be a line like `send host-name = gethostname();` in your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Put into /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:

```
send host-name "yourhostname"
```

and remove "host-name" from the "request" statement.

Comment: I already did that... but still doesn't work :-(

Comment: Hmm, sorry to hear. After due restarts (of the router, too), I suppose.

Comment: I see no reason to remove the `host-name` request option; DNS resolution works fine with that option here (Debian 7.0 with dhclient 4.2.4 connected to a Linksys WRT54GL). In any event, the logfiles should tell what happened, and `dhclient -v` or `service networking restart` on the client(s) should suffice.